# problem with ubuntu 14.04 installing, grub rescue

Tags: boot, upgrade, grubrescue

i tried to update ubuntu 12.04 lts to 14.04 lts. but I did an dumb mistake. My computer was not responding during update , so i foolishly shut down my laptop. but i managed to install other things after that. but i wasn't unable to install grub new version. so when i restart my laptop , it can't boot because there is something missing to boot. and "grub rescue>" prompt appeared. i don't know about these things , so i want help.
i tried to search about this on google but everyone is saying to have live cd or usb . so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually managed to install other things just fine, then all you have to do is **Boot Repair** and yes you have to create a live (boot-able) USB drive. Here is a very easy way to create one and for that you'll need:

1. Ubuntu 14.04 .iso file. If you do not have the .iso file, you can download it from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) (either direct download or torrent download, whichever you prefer).
2. An empty USB drive of size 1.5 GB or more.
3. A Windows OS with administrative permission
4. This software [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

When you have these things:

- Just run the Universal USB Installer.
- Select "Ubuntu" from the list of Linux Distributions.
- Browse to the location of the .iso file and select it.
- Select the letter of your USB and click create. Any previously stored data on USB will be lost.

After creating the boot-able USB, just plug it in your computer and turn it on. To make sure your computer boots from USB, you may have to **select "Boot Device options"** (by either pressing Esc or F12 depending on your computer) and then selecting USB drive from the list.

Once you boot your computer from USB, Just follow the **EXACT** procedure for Boot-Repair as given on the [Ubuntu Wiki](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops, maybe desktops, are problems for the latest versions of Ubuntu.  This is because Grub2 doesn't always get things right.  **Boot Repair** will tell you if this is a problem and offer to replace grub as a means of fixing it.  I did that, and it worked for me.  But there were manual commands the **Boot Repait** told me to enter as well

If you did not finish the install process, you will be missing stuff.  Getting the system up and running is not enough, as that is all handled in the early disk writing stages.  To properly fix your system, you really need to do a reinstall.

Reinstall is not that difficult.  Instead of choosing one of the other options listed on the page of how to install, you pick the last option, which is probably labeled "Something else".  Here you have choices, and you need to duplicate your original install as to disk(s) partition(s) assignments, use the same drive structure, but don't click on the Format button for the disk partition that has the /home folder.  Most people likely default to just drive /dev/sda1, ext4, everything there, and a swap partition as well. If you don'r know what your original structure us, yse the LiveCD or boot up and run gparted.  It can tell you a lot.

If you format the partition with /home on it, you wipe out your user accounts and data, and we usually want to avoid that.  Two alternatives are to install the operating system to a different drive, but keep the /home directory where it is, or later merge the old /home directory with a new one set up on a different partition.  You also have the option of backing up /home to a different location and bringing it back later.

I can't say that a reinstall is absolutely necessary, but it does resolve the question of whether you are missing anything or not. Something that might be hard to determine otherwise.  .